# How to know someones coords using block patterns

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've heard that you can find someones coords just with a screenshot and seeing the grass, sand etc patterns. Is it true? If its true, how can I use it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! If you haven't already, please take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help centre](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about how this site works.

Comment: Can you give an example of where this has been used? It's common practise to just press `F3` so that your coordinates come up on the screen.

Comment: @Aric I think he means finding the coordinates from any random screenshot. But yes, FiiVee7, an example where you heard that would be helpful.

Comment: My guess: The "random" texture rotations depend on location only, not seed, just like bedrock does (or did?), so when seeing enough of them, you should be able to get the location. But you would have to calculate the pattern back to the numbers that generated them, which is likely to be extremely hard. Also, to get it for certain, even if north isn't marked, you would need to see at least a 6x6 patch, even if there are no repetitions and the pattern is perfect for encoding the coordinates (which it likely isn't, so you would need an even bigger patch).